# php calling variable within complex quotations

Tags: php, variables, quotations

I'm trying to call a variable with a command that I need to send to windows CLI with no luck, if you could please help me out

```
$imagename = 123;

$test = ('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt "c:\pathtodirectory\$imagename" "photoprint""');
echo $test
```

`$imagename` currently has a value of 123 but I am unable to call it within several quotations please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Functions and methods are "called", variables are "used", "referred to" or "interpolated".

Comment: I don't think the quotes will work, even outside of PHP.  You've got unescaped quote blocks inside of quote blocks.  I think Windows would throw a fit about that before you got to any of your other issues.

Comment: sorry about the called vs used im just to bumped with trying to get this to work and the command does work if I use it with a file name and not try to use a variable, just that im confused with so many quotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one?

```
$imagename = 123;
$test = 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt "c:\pathtodirectory\\' . $imagename . '" "photoprint"';
echo $test;
```

Comment: yup that one works can I use the $test with exec or shell_exec?

Comment: The second parameter of `exec()` will be an array containing each line of the command output; `shell_exec()` returns a string containing the output of the command. It is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial string is within single quotes and PHP does not parse variables within single quoted strings.

Try either
`$test = ("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c \"rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt \"c:\pathtodirectory\$imagename\" \"photoprint\"\"");`

or
`$test = ('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt ' . "\"c:\pathtodirectory\$imagename\"" . ' "photoprint""');`

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt "c:\pathtodirectory$imagename" "photoprint"" I still get the $imagename instead of the 123